# How to get child model related data in parent model query

Tags: python, django

I have two models:

```
class BusinessCard(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(_("name"),null=True,max_length=50)


class Contacts(models.Model):
      businesscard_id = models.OneToOneField(BusinessCard,null=True,blank=True,related_name='contact_detail',db_column="businesscard_id")
      bcard_json_data = JsonField(null=True)
```

I just want access contacts model data using business card model:
`target_bacard=BusinessCard.objects.filter(id=target_bacard_id).select_related()`

When we access the `target_bacard.contact_detail` it gives key errors.
How can I get the contacts data using target_bacard queryset.

Comment: `businesscard_id` is a misleading name, since `contact.businesscard_id` does not give you an id but an actual model instance of BusinessCard. If this is how you got `target_bacard_id` it would explain that the query fails.

Comment: I guess user3048148 have used businesscard_id just as a placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `get()` instead of `filter()` like:

```
target_bacard = BusinessCard.objects.get(id=target_bacard_id)
target_bacard.contact_detail
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the Contacts instance that is in the 1-to-1 relationship with a BusinessCard instance *bacard*, use the related name you specified in *Contacts*:

```
contact = bacard.contact_detail
```

Also, you have some misleading names: *Contacts* should rather be *Contact* since an instance of this model represents only one contact. And its field *businesscard_id* would better be named *businesscard* (note that the table  column will be called *businesscard_id* at the database level automatically in that case and store the id of the related businesssscard) because in the ORM you get a BusinessCard model instance when you access it, and not just its *id*.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Also I am able to access the contacts info when I have used get instead of filter.

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed related model (field) argument to select_related()

```
target_bacard=BusinessCard.objects.filter(id=target_bacard_id).select_related('contact_detail')
```

Assuming `id` of  BusinessCard is unique, you may want to use `...objects.get(id=target_bacard_id)` inplace of `...objects.filter(id=target_bacard_id)`. Anyway select_related() will work on both ways.

select_related() is used for saving database query.
here is the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related)